# Javascript Object.seal() does not throw an exception

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5

I wanted to emulate something like a fixed object, so that no new members can be added to an object. `Object.seal(Obj)` seemed the right way, but it does not throw an exception when I try to create the new member. The member is not created, but it happens in silence.

```
var O = { a: 111 }
Object.seal(O)
O.b = 222  <------ here the exception is expected (trying to add a member "b")
O.a = 333
console.log(O) // { a: 333 }
```

Why would somebody want this silent behavior, why an exception is not thrown?

Comment: The code *doesn't* add a new member.

Comment: See Allen's answer -- you will get an exception, but only in strict mode.

Answer (score 4):

The behaviour of an assignment to a sealed object changes with the browsers. The latest release of chrome, for example, behaves as you might expect.
For practical purposes, it is safe to assume that adding a member to a sealed object only throws an exception when in strict mode.

```
;(function () {
    'use strict';
    var O = { a: 111 }
    Object.seal(O)
    O.b = 222
    O.a = 333
    console.log(O) // { a: 333 }
}());
```

This self-invoking anonymous function throws an error, as you expect.
On old browser, unfortunately, you cannot rely on polyfills such as 
https://github.com/kriskowal/es5-shim

In fact, the `seal` method on the prototype of Object avoids a 'TypeError' exception, but fails silently when invoked.
From the documentation:

> This should be fine unless you are depending on the safety and
>   security provisions of this method, which you cannot possibly obtain
>   in legacy engines.

Answer (score 2):

An assignment to a non-existent property of a non-extensible object is specified to throw, but only if the assignment is contained within strict-mode code. See the 4th bullet item of [ES5.1 Annex C](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-C).

If you want to make sure you get an exception, make sure you tag you code using "use strict";

The reason such an assignment doesn't throw in non-strict code is to maintain backwards compatibility with code conforming to the ES3 (or older) version of the ECMAScript standard.  The extensible/non-extensible concept did not exist prior to ES5, but some implementations may have exposed host objects (ie, DOM objects) to which properties could not be added.  Using the ES3 semantics, assignment to those objects would not throw.